# What caused these shallow depressions in a European forest?

Tags: zoology, soil

Recently, in an eastern European forest, I came across many depressions in the ground of a regular round shape, with a flat bottom and vertical walls.
Many were filled with water.
Some were obviously dug recently.
At the same time, there were no traces of excavated soil nearby.
I have no idea what kind of creature could do this, and why.
Has anyone come across something like this?
What it is?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where in the world were these photos taken? - I'm guessing Eastern Europe from your name. Could be soil sampling for a science study.

Comment: @bob1 yes, you're right, it's Eastern Europe

Comment: Another, more cynical, suggestion - any rare/valuable/collectable plants in the area?

Comment: Or elephants? ;p

Comment: @bob1, "Another, more cynical, suggestion - any rare/valuable/collectable plants in the area?" I did not see anything like it there, although I looked carefully enough, because I picked mushrooms.
besides, it is unlikely that the correct shape of the pits will be important for thieves

Comment: Could be that something was burried there... I like to dig out historical artefacts (others call it junk :D) and those holes made me think of when I dig out an old pot or something like that, that is laying in the ground.

Comment: @nika I agree, though there most people would leave the soil behind and perhaps pile it to the side, which we don't see here. This was why I was suggesting perhaps plant collectors or someone doing a soil survey.

Comment: @nika I did not specify the number of artifacts. there were about a hundred of them, or more. many could simply not visible, because the grass was overgrown.
this is a young forest on the territory of an abandoned boarding house, so the presence of antiquities in the soil is very unlikely.

Comment: It looks like a horse hoof print in soggy ground.